# C# user_nicename and Display name blank

Tags: users, mysql

I'm writing a C# application to add subscribers to wordpress.  The problem I'm having is the user_nicename and display_name fields in the database are showing but in the WordPress Users interface the Nickname is blank and there is a blank section in the Display name publicly as field.
What am I missing?

Thanks

```
 ds = new DataSet();
 userAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`, `coop_statementDate`, `coop_current_acc`, `coop_reimb_cred`, `coop_fund_bal`) VALUES(NULL, '"+txtLoginName.Text+"', MD5('{"+txtPassword.Text+"}'), '"+txtLoginName.Text+"', '"+txtEmail.Text+"', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000', '', '0', '"+txtCompanyName.Text+ "', '', '', '', '');", conn);
 userAdapter.Fill(ds,"wp_users");
```

Comment: I don't have a WordPress database to hand to check, but I'd compare your records to WordPress-generated records, including the values in wp_usermeta for the same users.

Comment: However on a C# point you should probably be using a pararmeterised MySqlCommand rather than constructing a SQL string by appending strings, especially without any escaping, for the usual SQL-injection reasons.

Comment: And you could also instead use your site's REST API (with authentication) to create users rather than going directly to the database if that's causing you problems.